# Extract iframes using BeautifulSoup with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, canvas-lms

I use the Canvas LMS and I want to extract the iframe from some pages to change the src content.
I try the following:

```
//some code
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
pretty_html = soup.prettify()
soup = BeautifulSoup(pretty_html, 'html.parser')
iframe = soup.find('iframe')
print(iframe)
```

But the result is unexpected, I got this as a result:

```
None
None
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="276" mozallowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" src="https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/%20f2c5f6ca3a4610c55d70cb211ef9d977" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="490"></iframe>
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

I was expecting only get this

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="276" mozallowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" src="https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/%20f2c5f6ca3a4610c55d70cb211ef9d977" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="490"></iframe>
```

The page html received has only one iframe, what is wrong with the result? I think I should receive only one iframe object, but it appears that I receive a list. Someone can clarify for me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discover how to fix the problem.

I change the code:

```
iframe = soup.find('iframe')
```

to

```
iframe = soup.find_all('iframe')
```

Then, instead of getting None as a response, I begin to receive []. An empty value.

I tested it using:

```
if iframes != [] :
    print( iframes[0]['src'] )
```

I got the content of src using the iframes[0]['src']